# Postfix won't allow external connections for port 25

Tags: email, telnet, centos7, postfix-mta

I have installed postfix, but for some time having trouble with it.

I am able to connect to port 25 on local host, but when I telnet port 25 from an external machine, the connection appears to be made but then hungs up.

I get the response:

> 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server xx.xxx.xx.xxx (xx.xx.xx.xxx:25),
>   connect error 10061 Connection closed by foreign host.

I have inet_interfaces set to all.

**main.cf**

```
soft_bounce = no
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
myorigin = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/


debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

**master.cf**

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

**netstat -plnt | grep 25**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10742/master
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      10742/master
```

Comment: This question belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) as it's related to infrastructure, not programming per-se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incoming connections to smtp port may be blocked by a firewall.

You may try to use tools like `tcptraceoute` to locate such firewalls.

Comment: I get the result:{ traceroute to mydomain.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (xx.x.x.x)  1.784 ms  0.969 ms  1.519 ms
 2  xx.xxx.xx.xxx (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) <syn,ack>  2.765 ms  1.408 ms  1.804 ms}

Comment: I get the same response with tcptraceroute, am running on CentOS7.

Comment: I noticed there was a port redirect on 25, so it could not be accessed, once the port redirect was removed, then postfix was able to get email.